# How to receive checked items from ListView?

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin.android

I have a `List<>` of items which are stored in a `ListView` with `CheckBox`'es. What I need is to store checked items to another `List<>`. Here is the code how the `ListView` is displayed and populated with data:

```
        List<Product> _productsList = ProductsFromXml();

        List<Product> checkedProducts = new List<Product>();

        productsListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
        productsListView.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItemMultipleChoice, _productsList);
        productsListView.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Multiple;
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok. Below is the c# code:

```
foreach (ListViewItem xitem in productsListView.CheckedItems)
{
     // Do whatever you want with checked item 'xitem'
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your documentation is about c#? Because I've tried your line and system says, that there is no such method.

Comment: It doesn't work anyways :( I mean, `CheckedItems` as a mehtod doesn't exist